# Suppose that $T: V \to V$ such that T(X)=AXB. Show that Rank(T)=Rank(A)Rank(B)

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose that $V=\mathbb{R^{m\times n}}$. Let $A \in \mathbb{R^{m \times m}}, B \in \mathbb{R^{n \times n}}$. Let $T: V \to V$ defined by $T(X)=AXB$. Show that $Rank(T)=Rank(A)Rank(B)$.

I tried to find out the null space of $T$. Let $X$ be in nullspace of $T$. Then $T(X)=AXB=0$. Now $AXB=0 \iff AXBv=0$ for all $v \in \mathbb{R^m} \iff$ $XBv \in Null(A)$ for all $v \iff X(y) \in Null(A) \forall y \in Range(B) $.

I am unable to conclude anything from here. Any hints will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\newcommand{\ha}{\hat{a}}$ $\newcommand{\hb}{\hat{b}}$
Suppose that $A$ has rank $r$ and $B$ has rank $q$. Let $\mathcal{A} = \{\ha_1,\ldots,\ha_{m-r}\}$ be a basis for the nullspace of $A$ and let $\mathcal{B} = \{\hb_1,\ldots,\hb_{n-q}\}$ be a basis for the left nullspace of $B$. Extend $\mathcal{A}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^m$ and extend $\mathcal{B}$ to a basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$. It is easy to show that 
$$\{\ha_i\hb_j^T\,|\,i=1,\ldots,m,~j = 1,\ldots,n\}$$ 
forms a basis for $\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$. By the definition of $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathcal{B}$ it is clear that

$$
A\ha_i\hb_j^TB = 0 \iff i \not\in\{m-r+1,\ldots,m\} \lor j \not\in\{n-q+1,\ldots,n\}
$$

Therefore, the dimension of the kernel of $T$ is $mn - rq$. It now follows by the Rank-Nullity Theorem that the rank of $T$ is $rq$.